# JEditorPane vs JTextPane vs JTextArea for center align text and word-wrap

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I'm trying to display some center align text that also word wraps.

My initial thought was using a JTextArea but I found no way to center align the text.

For this I found most people recommended using a JTextPane, which it allowed me to align the text as I wanted but it does not wrap the text, it just keeps all the text in one line.

This how I found a way to center align the text with the JTextPane

```
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 60));
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

I didn't find a way to set the wrap with the JTextPane, what I did find was most people recommend using a JTextArea or a JEditorPane.

The JEditorPane does a single-letter wrap but once again I didn't find a way to center align the text.

So, is there a way to have both a text wrap and center align text? Which component would be better for it?

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is you need a JFrame with the JTextPane. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and text the code to see the problem described. You can also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176138/131872 for different examples with a JTextPane.

Comment: “a JTextPane … just keeps all the text in one line.”  That typically happens when you neglect to place it in a JScrollPane.  JTextArea, JEditorPane, and JTextPane all *must* be placed in a JScrollPane.

Comment: @camickr I just added the text I needed directly  in the code with the method `setText()` and it seems to be working just fine now. I'm not sure what happened earlier but problem solved I guess.